# Sabre - How many steps to request the Void Air Ticket?

Tags: sabre, sabredav

I have a problem with request void air ticket requests. Before void ticket requests, what I need to do first? I have tried my workflow as below:

> **SessionCreateRQ** => **TravelItineraryReadRQ** => **VoidTicketLLSRQ** => **EndTransactionLLSRQ**

Void Ticket Request:

```xml
{{soapHeader}}
<soapenv:Body>
        <ns:VoidTicketRQ  Version="2.1.0">
            <ns:Ticketing  eTicketNumber="8165070132526"/>
        </ns:VoidTicketRQ>
</soapenv:Body>
{{soapFooter}}
```

Void Ticket Response:

```xml
<soap-env:Body>
        <VoidTicketRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.1.0">
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
                <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2021-06-30T22:55:13-05:00">
                    <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                        <stl:Message>NO TCN/AT NBR MATCH-VERIFY-POSSIBLE MANUAL RFND REQUIRED-0093</stl:Message>
                        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                    </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
        </VoidTicketRS>
</soap-env:Body>
```

Answer (score 2):

To void a ticket you need to perform following steps:

- Open a session using `SessionCreateRQ`. Please note, that you void
  tickets in the same PCC where tickets have been issued. You may use
  `ContextChangeLLSRQ` to switch contexts.
- You may also need to assign a ticket printer with `DesignatePrinterLLSRQ`.
- Load a booking to the session with `TravelItineraryReadRQ` or `GetReservationRQ`.

Now you may call the void method. Void operation is a two-step, so you must call void method twice to confirm void.

In the void request you use eTicketNumber. As Sabre docs state (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/fulfill/Void_Air_Ticket):

> Please note that @eTicketNumber is only applicable to Sabre Sonic Res-hosted clients

Maybe, this is why you got the error. You may use RPH instead. RPH is an "index" attribute of the `TicketingInfo/TicketDetails/TicketNumber` node.

Also consider that voiding tickets does not automatically cancel booking, so you may want to use `OTA_CancelLLSRQ` method to completely finish the invalidation process.

Comment: [@Christina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5384089/christina)Thanks for the helpful answer! I tried successfully by using RPH.